# Find and replace date/time in string

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, osx-snow-leopard

I have already made a regex which should work, but it doesn't work.

```
echo "FileName.17:09:2010 4.16.PM.720p.mp4" | sed -E 's/\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{4}\ (\d|\d{2})\.(\d{2}|\d)\.((AM)|(PM))//g'
```

Should output: FileName..720p.mp4

But instead outputs the same "FileName.17:09:2010 4.16.PM.720p.mp4".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `\d` a valid character class in [sed](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html)? Try replacing it with `[0-9]` or `[:digit:]`. See [re_format](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/re_format.7.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/7/re_format).

Comment: Also, you could simplify your regex by removing unnecessary alternates to `sed -E 's/[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+ [0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.(AM|PM)//g'`.

Comment: Yeah thought about that when I made the regex but thought it would do a better match if I done it with the exact number of numbers. Though it is allot neater.

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /bin/sh
f="FileName.17:09:2010 4.16.PM.720p.mp4"
echo ${f%%.*}${f##*[AP]M}
```

This works for any variable containing a string matching the pattern. See [Parameter Expansion for shell variables](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02).

With sed, just delete from the first dot to the AM or PM. Or, if the filename could have extraneous dots, then delete from the 1st number folowed by ':' up to [AP]M, `'s/\.[0-9]\+:.*\[AP]M//'`

I think the sed way might be better; because if it fails it returns the original string.  A mismatch on the shell expression would return some of the name twice; but error checking can be added easily: It fails for files not having AM or PM in the name.

```
echo FileName.17:09:2010 4.16.PM.720p.mp4|sed  -e 's/\..*[AP]M\././'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bash$ echo "FileName.17:09:2010 4.16.PM.720p.mp4"|ruby -e 's=gets.chomp.split(".");puts [s[0],s[-2,2]].join(".")'
FileName.720p.mp4
```